# Stopwatch - NSTimer or NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to implement a timer that counts up every second. I have 2 ways in mind, but am kinda confused about which one is the optimal way to do it. It's either using NSTimer or NSDate, and as I understand NSTimer is usually only used to fire methods, so maybe I shouldn't use NSTimer but NSDate?

Some clarification would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`NSDate` is a model class. It doesn't fire or do anything except represent a certain date and time. You will have to use both (`NSTimer` and `NSDate`) for you stopwatch. When you start the watch save the current date in an `NSDate` instance and start an NSTimer with a 1 sec interval (or more if you want to display milliseconds). And everytime the timer fires, you calculate the difference between the current date and the saved date and show it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSTimer to update your UI periodically. Use NSDate to get the precise time on each update.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the NSTimer. It will wait a certain time and then fire an event to a specified object. NSDate just gives you a single point in time which is immutable. Please check the docs. Thanks!

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "counts up"? What do you want to do when it "counts up"?

Basically, you can always use NSDate to store a "Start date", and then whenever you feel like it you can get the difference between "now" and that stored date.

On the other hand, if you want a ticking clock on the screen you would use an NSTimer that fires every second to tell your application to update the clock.

There is almost no usecase for some integer variable somewhere that just increases every second without anyone looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use NSTimer. You can start the timer with

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateSeconds)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and in your `updateSeconds` method:

```
(void)updateSeconds
{
    int seconds = [self.secondsLabel.text intValue];
    seconds = seconds + 1;
    self.secondsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seconds];
}
```

Note that `secondsLabel` is an IBOutlet connected to the label which displays the elapsed time in seconds.