# I have a NSDate, how do i show a stopwatch that auto updates showing a timer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, timer, nsdate, stopwatch

I have a NSDate variable. From that variable, how I can show a stopwatch that continuously updates in the view?

I've tried `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval]` but can't get it working but also doubt that is the ideal way to do that.

Comment: here you go buddy http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jmTQi98vec

Comment: This question is asked at least once every two months.  Try finding one of the prior versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopwatch - NSTimer or NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375304/stopwatch-nstimer-or-nsdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **this**

```
- (void)updateTimer
{
    static NSInteger counter = 0;
    [stopWatchLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Counter: %i", counter++]];
}

- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender {
    startDate = [[NSDate date]retain];

    // Create the stop watch timer that fires every 10 ms
    stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
}
```

You have to connect the IBAction to a button, and the stopWatchLabel to a UILabel in the interface builder.

Found on: http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_ios_stopwatch.php

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem with [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)?

```
- (void)startTimer {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/30.0f
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                   userInfo:[NSDate date]
                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSDate *startDate = timer.userInfo;
    NSTimeInterval secondsPassed = -[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    // Update your label here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ve tried this, its working

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)timerCallback{
    NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
}
```

update timeInterval argument to what you want, and display it in view(I have just printed log);

I got this log:

```
2012-09-12 18:04:11.252 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:11 +0000
2012-09-12 18:04:12.170 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:12 +0000
2012-09-12 18:04:13.170 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:13 +0000
2012-09-12 18:04:14.170 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:14 +0000
2012-09-12 18:04:15.170 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:15 +0000
2012-09-12 18:04:16.170 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:16 +0000
2012-09-12 18:04:17.170 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:17 +0000
2012-09-12 18:04:18.170 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:18 +0000
2012-09-12 18:04:19.171 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:19 +0000
2012-09-12 18:04:20.170 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:20 +0000
2012-09-12 18:04:21.170 S[19550:f803] 2012-09-12 12:34:21 +0000
```